# Chabad Yeshiva Ketana?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, chabad, yeshiva-school

Does anyone know a Chabad Yeshiva in Eretz Yisroel for boys aged 15/16 preferably with a summer program? Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Lev and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!